# VB.NET - Focus first row and first cell of DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, focus

Good morning,

I have a form with two textbox and a DataGridView.
I'm used to fill my controls then i press Tab to switch to the next one.

However, when i switch from my textbox to my DataGridView, the selected cell is the second one of the first row => DTG.Rows(0).Cells(1).
I need to enter on the DTG.Rows(0).Cells(0) to fill my DTG without using my mouse.

I tried the code bellow :

```
Public Sub txtBoxTest_Leave() Handles txtBoxTest.Leave
        DTG.Focus()
        DTG.CurrentCell = DTG(0, 0)
        DTG.BeginEdit(True)
End Sub
```

The cell seems to be selected, but it is not in editmode.

Modify the edit mode to EditOnEnter does not resolve my problem :

```
DTG.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
```

Can someone help me please ?

**EDIT :** 
My datagridview cells are in `ReadOnly = False`.

Comment: Are your datagridview, row, column and cell in `ReadOnly == false` ? How do you populate your datagridview ?

Comment: i edited my question, but the method to populate my DTG is not important here, because it is empty. I just need to enter in the good cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
        Dim cell as Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell= dataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0)
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell = cell
        DataGridView1.BeginEdit(True)
```

Comment: It is kinda similar to my code, but your is working.
Thank you very much. :)